# Q: R plot building footprint / outline on map using OpenStreetMap data

Tags: r, leaflet, openstreetmap, building, outline

I'm rather new to creating maps and stuff in R, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to plot a building outline in R using data from OpenStreetMap, instead of having to define a polygon myself for plotting the outline of the building. But I cannot get my head around it.

The example below is what I have done so far to get the location:

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng=10.153523, lat=57.207181, zoom = 16) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=10.153523, lat=57.207181, popup="My building example")
```

And the example building data is available on https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/481541280

How do I integrate this building outline data into my R script? Is there a neat way of doing this other than extracting the points one by one and making a polygon using leaflet in R?

Comment: you need to download either the shape file or the boundary coordinates of the shape of the building you want to plot. Once you do that you can just add another layer to the leaflet map with its appropriate attributes by piping to the end of the `addMarkers( )` method. You may need to use `rgdal` or `sp` to make the shape ready for incorporation.

Comment: Ok, so I guess it is not possible to directly reference a building from OpenStreetMap and assign it to my map as a layer. It just seems a bit like doing things twice, since a guy has already created and plotted the coordinates in OpenStreetMap, plus it is rather inconvenient to extract the coordinates from OpenStreetMap buildings as they are not provided as a vector but rather made up from independent markers. But I will do that then, thank you.